# Vue автоматически прикручивает div class="col col-4" к моему template

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Vuejs (возможно vuetify ?) автоматически создает данный div с классом col col-4

[image: browser code]

что вынуждает меня писать кастомные стили для того чтобы шаблон выглядел валидно
Я думаю что собака зарыта в vuetify библиотеке и прошу помощи с данным вопросом.
Если бы у даного div был class="col col-3" это бы полностью удовлетворило мои нужды в отсутсвии допиливания кастомных стилей.
Благодарю за будущие ответы, господа

Comment: переведите пожалуйста ваш вопрос на русский язык, так как он был задан на русском SO

Comment: @Andrew спасибо, исправил

Comment: только вручную, удалять эти классы. В хуке mounted

Comment: @Дмытрык не кажется ли это вам немного неправильным ?

Comment: Я читал Ваш вариант вопроса написанный на английском, и там Вы справшивали (как я понял): как удалить эти классы... Только так, как я написал выше. Вы же не хотите стили перебивать

Comment: Либо же, можно использовать соответствующий параметр в компоненте библиотеки, если такой есть

Comment: @Дмытрык я вас понял, то что вы сказали - сработало, но я продолжу искать истинный путь ) Спасибо

Comment: Истинный путь - перебить стили